# how to move files from one folder to other with appending time stamp to the name?

Tags: shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming a bunch of files with date modified timestamp at the end of the filename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43338/renaming-a-bunch-of-files-with-date-modified-timestamp-at-the-end-of-the-filenam)

I want to move files from one folder to another folder with appending time stamp to file names.

For example, I have two files called `file1` and `file2` in folder `f1`.

I want to move these files to folder `f2` as file names `file1_22_jan_11:42` and `file2_22_jan_11:42`.

Answer (score 1):

If that time stamp is meant to be the modification time of the file, with GNU find and xargs, you could do:

```
find f1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%p\0f2/%f_%Td_%Tb_%TH:%TM\0' |
  xargs -r0n2 echo mv
```

and remove `echo` when happy.

Answer (score 0):

To copy `somefile` to `otherplace/somefile_` with modification date appended (eg, 2012_12_06):

```
cp somefile otherplace/somefile_`stat --printf=%y somefile | sed -e 's/ .*//'`
```

Probably easiest if you put that in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

suffix=_`stat --printf=%y $1 | sed -e 's/ .*//'`
cp $1 $2/$1_$suffix
```

Name it 'mycp' and you can go:

```
mycp somefile otherplace
```

For the stat info, see `man stat`.