# How to bulk rename files to add modification date?

Tags: bash, rename

I have these files, which were modified today and yesterday, respectively:

```
a.txt
b.png
```

And I want them renamed to:

```
2020-02-01.a.txt
2020-01-31.b.png
```

How to do that in a single Bash command?

Comment: Possibly related [Renaming a bunch of files with date modified timestamp at the end of the filename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43338/renaming-a-bunch-of-files-with-date-modified-timestamp-at-the-end-of-the-filenam).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming a bunch of files with date modified timestamp at the end of the filename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43338/renaming-a-bunch-of-files-with-date-modified-timestamp-at-the-end-of-the-filenam)

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | while read FILE; do mv "$FILE" "$(stat "$FILE" -c '%y' | cut -b -10). $FILE"; done
```

Tested on Git Bash on Windows and Linux Mint.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Perl-based `rename` utility:

```
$ rename -n 'use POSIX qw(strftime); s/^/strftime("%Y-%m-%d.",localtime((stat $_)[9]))/e' *.*
rename(a.txt, 2020-02-01.a.txt)
rename(b.png, 2020-02-01.b.png)
```

(On some systems, `rename` may be provided as `prename`).

Comment: this just prints 'rename(f, f2)' it doesn't actually do anything to the files.